# How to draw a layer on stage by json in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

There is a method in KineticJS to draw a stage (canvas) from json

```
Kinetic.Node.create(JSON, 'container');
```

There are many layers on stage. I have saved a layer in to JSON

How can I draw just one layer on existing stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use AJAX to execute the code?

```
 $.ajax(
   url:
   success: function(response){
      stage.add(new Kinetic.Layer());
   }
 );
```

You can make this dependent on what is stored in your JSON object.